# jms serializer groups not working in child entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, jms, serialization

jms serializer groups not working in child entities

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"public"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"public"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SkUserCategory", mappedBy="user")
     * @Groups({"public"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $categories;
}


class SkUserCategory
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\SkCategory
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SkCategory", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     * @Groups({"public"})
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     */
    private $user;
}
```

Im not getting category data while fetching user details with serialization groups set to `"public"`

Answer (score 0):

You must configure which fields you want to keep in the serialization process **as well** in the **SkCategory** entity with the annotation @Groups({"public"}).

Comment: thankyou.. Is exclusion policy and group concept contradictory...?